# Where can I find a HBase cascading module for hbase-0.89.20100924+28?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, cascading

I am working on a project using map reduce and HBase. We are using
Cloudera’s CDH3 distribution which has hbase-0.89.20100924+28 bundled
into it. I would like to use cascading as we have some processing that
requires multiple map reduce jobs, but I have been looking through the
different forks of the HBase adaptors for cascading on github and
can’t seem to find one for our version of HBase. Could someone point
me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

We are using https://github.com/ryanobjc/cascading.hbase with CDH3u1. If you have not tried that one with CDH3 give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like timestamped version comming from source control. Can't you just extract it from tarball/jar file?

Comment: Sense. Your answer makes none.

Comment: @Bryan Nope, your coment is senceless. I have proposed 2 methods - getting it from repo using date as a marker and extracting it from distribution.

Comment: There are many many forks of the Cascading-HBase module, but I have yet to be able to fully compile any of the versions I have stumbled upon, which I believe is because of conflicts in the versions each one is written for.